# Why in some cases are used only the first x chars of a md5 hash instead of using all of them?

Tags: cryptography, md5, hash

For example commit list on GitHub shows only first 10, or this line from tornadoweb which uses only 5

```
return static_url_prefix + path + "?v=" + hashes[abs_path][:5]
```

Are only the first 5 chars enough to make sure that 2 different hashes for 2 different files won't collide?

LE: The example above from tornadoweb uses md5 hash for generating a query sting for static file caching.

Comment: A large part of the answer depends on what your app will do given a partial hash collision. In the case of git, it will refuse to do anything, and list the complete hashes that match that prefix - which is a good failure mode.

Comment: Actually, Git uses SHA-1, not MD5, for hashes for commits, trees and blobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In general, No.**

In fact, even if a full MD5 hash were given, it wouldn't be enough to prevent malicious users from generating collisions---MD5 is broken. Even with a better hash function, five characters is not enough.

**But sometimes you can get away with it.**

I'm not sure exactly what the context of the specific example you provided is. However, to answer your more general question, if there aren't bad guys actively trying to cause collisions, than using part of the hash is probably okay. In particular, given 5 hex characters (20 bits), you won't expect collisions before around 2^(20/2) = 2^10 ~ one thousand values are hashed. This is a consequence of the the [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox).

The previous paragraph assumes the hash function is essentially random. This is *not* an assumption anyone trying to make a cryptographically secure system should make. But as long as no one is intentionally trying to create collisions, it's a reasonable heuristic.

Comment: s/get a way/get away/ - quite different meanings. :) Also, 5 hexadecimal digits is 2.5 bytes (20 bits).

Comment: @NickJohnson: Thanks for the corrections. Seems like I also wrote "its" instead of "it's"... time to perform seppuku. :)

Comment: Git uses SHA-1 instead of MD5, which makes your first sentence less relevant (SHA-1 is not yet broken).